# How can I know which action is triggered with shortcut in KDE?

Tags: emacs, archlinux, kde-plasma

I have installed KDE in my Arch system, after this I installed some effects and stuff.

Then I have installed emacs. And when I try to execute a command with `Alt` + `Alt Gr` do nothing.

For example, I want to delete the spaces in a line with the command `Alt` + `Alt Gr` + `\` but nothing happens.

So I want to know how can I know what is this binded or how can I make it work as expected.

Im using emacs 27.2

My keyboard layout is spanish.

If I use the following combination it works: `Esc` + `Alt Gr` + `\`

Answer (score 1):

you need to install qt5-tools from [the arch repository](https://archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/qt5-tools/)

open up the application called `qbusviewer`

under the session-bus tab search for org.kde.kglobalaccel

in the right hand part you would see a method list select

```
component/ khotkeys / org.kde.kglobalaccel.Component /
```

click on `signal: globalShortcutPressed`

now when you press a shortcut it shows at the bottom pane in the application.

Answer (score 0):

Speaking from KDE side, you can check if the key is bound in your system settings by navigating to "System Settings" > "Shortcuts" and searching for that specific key. If no results are found, probably how you have assigned its action in emacs could have some issue. Maybe see if there's anything in the "Messages" buffer.

[image: NA]